# How do i convert a for loop into a list comprehension or a lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to basically optimize this function which is either by creating a list comprehension or a lambda function :

```
def incremental_id(data, datecol, id_col):
    # Input - Data, Date_column, Custno_column
    response = pd.DataFrame()
    init_index = data.index.tolist()
    for customer in data[id_col].unique():
        data_sub = data[data[id_col] == customer]
        data_sub = data_sub.sort_values(datecol, ascending=True)
        data_sub['Incremental_id'] = np.arange(data_sub.shape[0])
        response = response.append(data_sub)
    response = response.reindex(index=init_index)
    return response
```

Comment: Did you try to use either a list comprehension or a lambda function? Did you encounter any issues?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't enjoy trying to guess from your code what you are trying to do and what the variable types might possibly be.